# Running Tornado with Python 3.2

Tags: python, tornado

I just started out with Python and wanted to try out tornado.

Running the example from tornado website

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r'C:\Python32\tornado-2.3')

import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write("Hello, world")

application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/", MainHandler),
])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

I got the following error:

```
File "C:\Python32\tornado-2.3\tornado\ioloop.py", line 302
except Exception, e:
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I Installed Python 3.2 on Windows 7 machine.

Does anyone know what could be the cause for exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python 3, [you must use the `as` keyword.](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3110/), i.e.

```
except Exception as e:
```

Run

```
python3 setup.py build
```

in the `C:\Python32\tornado-2.3` directory to generate a Python3 build (with 2to3) in `tornado/build/lib`.